# Installing MariaDB with different account

Tags: services, mariadb, accounts

I would like to install MariaDB on Ubuntu with a different account. What I see ? If I simple `apt install mariadb-server` it deploys MariaDB with `mysql` user and `mysql` group. I tried first to reconfigure the service itself under `/bin/systemd/system/mariadb.service` change from `User=mysql` to `User=jdoe` but start of the service failed. `journalctl -xe` clearly states it is permission issue. (I am not 100% sure but I guess `jdoe` user has not got permissions on certain directories and files.) Anyway I have two options now. I ask about how to change the from `mysql` user properly to `jdoe` by configuring the service or I ask about how to deploy mariadb initially with different user.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think I have found something: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=